# Clear retrofit result with MVVM when fragment back

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

In my ViewModel I have two MutableLiveData for the response of my webservice :

```
val getFindByCategorySuccess: MutableLiveData<List<DigitalService>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<DigitalService>>()
    }

val getFindByCategoryError: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
```

and this method for the request :

```
fun requestFindByCategory(categoryId: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when (val retrofitPost = digitalServicesRemoteRepository.getFindByCategoryRequest(categoryId)) {
                is ApiResult.Success -> getFindByCategorySuccess.postValue(retrofitPost.data)
                is ApiResult.Error -> getFindByCategoryError.postValue(retrofitPost.exception)
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working fine using it in my Fragment class :

```
viewModel.getFindByCategorySuccess.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { digitalServices ->
            logD("I have a good response from the webservice; luanch an other fragment now!")
        })
```

The problem is if I go to an other fragment in my observable (using `findNavController().navigate(action)`). If I go back to the previous fragment, I go automatically to the nextFragment because the observable is called again.

So I'm looking for solutions...
Maybe clearing all my viewmodel when I go back to my fragment ?
Maybe clearing only getFindByCategorySuccess and getFindByCategoryError ?
Maybe an other solution? I think my architecture is not good. What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem using this class :

```
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    private val mPending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        super.observe(owner, { t ->
            if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false))
                observer.onChanged(t)
        })
    }

    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        mPending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

}
```

Like this :

```
var getFindByCategorySuccess: SingleLiveEvent<List<DigitalService>> = SingleLiveEvent()

var getFindByCategoryError: SingleLiveEvent<String> = SingleLiveEvent()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, a livedata will emit to its current state (the value that exist on it)  for any new observer that subscribes to it.

Answering your question, you might try the operator [`distincUntilChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#distinctUntilChanged(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E)) transformation, which, according to the documentation:

> Creates a new LiveData object that does not emit a value until the source LiveData value has been changed. The value is considered changed if equals() yields false.

But, this showcases a problem with your snippet, and a bad practice that is common when using livedata, you shouldn't expose mutable live data to your observers. Instead, you should expose a non-mutable version of them.

In your case, in my opinion, your view model should look like the following:

```
private val getFindByCategorySuccess by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<DigitalService>>()
}

private val getFindByCategoryError by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<String>()
}

val onFindByCategorySuccess: LiveData<List<DigitalService>
    get() = getFindByCategorySuccess.distincUntilChanged()

val onFindCategoryError: LiveData<List<String>
    get() = getFindByCategoryrRror.distincUntilChanged()
```

And your observers would subscribe as follows:

> ExampleFragment

```
fun setupObservers() {
     viewModel.onFindByCategorySuccess.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { // Do stuff }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but I have the same problem using your solution :/

Comment: I enter on the observer of onFindByCategorySuccess when I back again to the fragment.

Comment: Where are you observing the livedatas in your first fragment?, maybe in `onResume`? 

if so, doing it at  `onActivityCreated` should solve your issue, would you try?. Anyway, if using the `distincUntilChanges` transformation still makes your LD emit values, means that your list might be different on any new request.

Comment: I'm doin it in onCreateView() method. onActivityCreated() doesn't change nothing.

Comment: The problem is : i'm getting the same result going back to my fragment. And I want an empty result (because I have to do a new request)

Comment: I found a solution but I'm not sure if it's good to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461059/5364583